# Como alterar o tamanho de uma tela através de um evento em C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Como é possível realizar uma alteração no tamanho de um Formulário(Window) em WPF, podendo alterar seu Heigth e Width e assim aumentando e diminuindo a tela de acordo com os valores informados?
Por exemplo: tenho um button (Aumentar a Tela)
e quando o evento refente a esse button é executado ocorre uma função

```
button_click(){
   Form.Width = NovoValor;
   Form.Heigth= NovoValor;
}
```

Comment: Acredito que os comandos certos são: `Form.Left`, `Form.Top`, e assim vai.

Comment: @Francisco Isso define posição, não tamanho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa também definir as propriedades `MinWidth` e `MinHeigth`.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MinWidth = novaLargura;
    Width = novaLargura;
    MinHeight = novaAltura;
    Height = novaAltura;
}
```

Comment: Eu estava tentando apenas com o Width e Heigth, não sabia que era necessário informar os Min... também! muito obrigado pela ajuda